# Where can I find Mondrian tutorial?

Tags: mondrian

I am having trouble finding how to create a simple web-app to analyse its 
data on OLAP cubes with Mondrian. I have a small database that consists 
only of one fact table and 2 dimension tables.

Is there a tutorial or a 
reference on how to build a web-app that will connect my 3 tables in a 
MySQL to a Mondrian web-app that allows MDX queries?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've found the documentation on http://sandbox.pentaho.com/ better than what's on the main site.  The Pentaho Solutions book is also good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good tutorial for beginners:
[Mondrian 4 get ready](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.mx/2013/01/mondrian-4-get-ready.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the [official documentation of Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a first time user, you can have a look at this site
http://pentaho-en.phi-integration.com/mondrian/configuring-mondrian-sample/jpivot-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

- [Developer's Guide](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/developers_guide.php).
- [API-functions](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/api/).